# Javascript: How to link two textbox based on a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

**Situation:** I have two textbox `textA` and `textB` and I have a sharepoint custom list `DataList` with two column `Name` and `ID`. I linked `textA` to `Name` and `textB` to `ID` with an autocomplete function (based on SPservice autocomplete) so if the user start to type something the options based on the columns appear in a dropdown menu and the user can select it. (The textfields are not the input fields of DataList they are just based on it).

**What I desire:** I would like to create a link between `textA` and `textB` so if the user select any value to `textA` or `textB` the other field is autofill by the element from the same row from `DataList`.

**The problem:** The column `ID` is unique but the `Name` is not. So if the user fill, `textB` with an ID the situation is simple just need to find the value from the same row and insert to `textA`. But if the user fill the `textA` there can be multiple IDs to fill the `textB`, so I would like to create a dropdown menu from the `textB` and make the user choose the desired ID (luckly the users know most of the ID by just looking on the numbers).

I am not sure if is this possible to create a dropdown menu like this and if yes, how?

**UPDATE:**

Using: jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js
Here is the code of the autocomplete of the ID in TextB:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
            sourceList: "{D445CA52-8F13-4EBB-A0AE-ABC96AD21C5F}",
            sourceColumn: "ID",
            columnName: "TextB",
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 2
   });
});
```

[image: Reaction = textA, INN NUmber = textB]

Using: sharepointplus-4.0.min.js
And here is my current code to autofill `textA` if uniqu ID is selected in `textB`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $SP().list("TargetedList","http://.../sites/Registry/").get(
        {
            fields: "Name",            
            where: 'ID = '+ Number(document.getElementById("TextB").value)
        },
        function getData(data) {alert(data.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i].getAttribute("Name"));
                $("input[id='TextA']").val(data[i].getAttribute("Name"));
            }
      });
    });
```

[image: Reaction = textA, INN NUmber = textB]

So this is working very well, but I can do this only cause ID is unique. I would like to do the same if textA's list value is selected. But textA is not unique so before fill the ID I need to open an another dropdown list of all ID with matches and if the user select the correct one, fill it to textB (Users know it just by looking on the IDs).

Comment: The best advice i can give you is to show us your code !